# how to integrate an MTN Momo or orange money payment system into your application. If we are not a company?

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, css

Integrate an MTN Momo and Orange Money payment system using their API
I also need another reliable and efficient way to integrate these different APIs
When wanting to integrate the API thanks to their website I was told that I needed the company's pap

Answer (score 0):

Before proceeding with your Mobile Money integration, I will advise you to first research the alternative platforms available that over the services to non-businesses. This will help you make a better decision and choose the platform that will work for you.

If you encounter any integration issues or problems, you can always ask the community for help. The Stack Overflow community is a great resource for developers looking for help with their coding challenges.

If you still want to proceed with MTN Momo, you can sign up to use their APIs by following the link below:

[https://momodeveloper.mtn.com/](https://momodeveloper.mtn.com)

Good luck with your integration!